# Covariance matrix for Complete blood count

Tags: blood-tests, cbc-complete-blood-count

What is known about a (multivariate) statistical distribution of complete blood count? Especially about the covariance or correlation matrix 
(in a healthy population).

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). This is an interesting question. Is there any research that you have done or any additional specific question? Anything you can add would help those who would try to answer. Thanks!

Comment: I have data about survival of haemodialisis (and complete blood count of HD patients, but no complete blood count of controll). So, I will use a charactersistic direction method, whether or not a characteristic direction predict mortality. 


About the characteristic direction method: 
https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2105-15-79

Comment: I see and I suggest that you edit your question to include the information you provided in the comment. The topic is definitely out of my scope and I can't help, but the additional information may be of use to someone who is knowledgeable on the subject and tries to answer your question.